# behavior of map's value pointer being added to slice

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go, slice

```
func TestMapValuePointer2(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("Test Map Value Pointer 2")
    m := map[string]int{"rsc": 3711, "r": 2138, "gri": 1908, "adg": 912}
    n := len(m)
    array := make([]*int, n)
    i := 0
    for _, v := range m {
        array[i] = &v
        fmt.Printf("Add to array: %d\n", v)
        i++
    }
    for _, k := range array {
        fmt.Printf("Value: %d\n", *k)
    }
}
```

The output is not:

```
Value: 912
Value: 3711
Value: 2138
Value: 1908
```

Instead, the output maybe like:

```
Value: 912
Value: 912
Value: 912
Value: 912
```

Can someone explain why the results are like the above?

Comment: You keep adding the same pointer to `v` to the slice. See also https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: If you want pointers you need to make your map's value a pointer type like `*int`. Map items can move around in memory, so you can't get a pointer directly into the map. [Here's a slightly expanded version of that.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32751792/2714852)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [this doc](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines):

> [...] each iteration of the loop uses the same instance of the variable v, so each closure shares that single variable [...]

In other words, the loop variable `v` is reused in all iterations, so your assigning the same pointer to all your slice elements.

Variables declared *inside* the loop won't be recycled like that, so this will work as you would expect:

```
for _, v := range m {
    vv := v
    array[i] = &vv
    fmt.Printf("Add to array: %d\n", v)
    i++
}
```

Btw, you haven't explained why you want to use `*int` as the type of the values. All this would be simpler if you used simply `int` values.

Comment: I am not sure what's OP expected value here, but doing it this way the pointers inside the array and map will now deference to different places.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the variable `v` created during the loop is actually a copy of the value we have in the map. The memory related to `v` is allocated once at the start of the loop and is re-used later on for other values, as the last value here points to is 912 in this case you're seeing 912 inside the array.

A simple proof for this will be: https://play.golang.org/p/K0yAbEIf3G

One fix for this will be to change your map value to be *int pointers instead of values and later on we can dereference them to get the actual values:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Test Map Value Pointer 2")
    a, b, c, d := 3711, 2138, 1908, 912
    m := map[string]*int{"rsc": &a, "r": &b, "gri": &c, "adg": &d}
    n := len(m)
    array := make([]*int, n)
    i := 0
    for _, v := range m {
        array[i] = v
        fmt.Printf("Add to array: %d\n", *v)
        i++
    }
    for _, k := range array {
        fmt.Printf("Value: %d\n", *k)
    }
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/TpkXlCElLx