# Golang syntax in "if" statement with a map

Tags: dictionary, if-statement, go, syntax

I am reading a tutorial here: http://www.newthinktank.com/2015/02/go-programming-tutorial/

On the "Maps in Maps" section it has:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    // We can store multiple items in a map as well

    superhero := map[string]map[string]string{
        "Superman": map[string]string{
            "realname":"Clark Kent",
            "city":"Metropolis",
        },

        "Batman": map[string]string{
            "realname":"Bruce Wayne",
            "city":"Gotham City",
        },
    }

    // We can output data where the key matches Superman

    if temp, hero := superhero["Superman"]; hero {
        fmt.Println(temp["realname"], temp["city"])
    }

}
```

I don't understand the "if" statement. Can someone walk me through the syntax on this line:

```
if temp, hero := superhero["Superman"]; hero {
```

Like `if temp` seems nonsensical to an outsider as temp isn't even defined anywhere. What would that even accomplish? Then `hero := superhero["Superman"]` looks like an assignment. But what is the semicolon doing? why is the final `hero` there?

Can someone help a newbie out?

Many thanks.

Comment: The [two-value form of map lookups is covered in the tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/22), as are [statements before if conditions](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/6).

Comment: Why not take the Tour of Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A two-value assignment tests for the existence of a key:

```
i, ok := m["route"]
```

> In this statement, the first value (i) is assigned the value stored
>   under the key "route". If that key doesn't exist, i is the value
>   type's zero value (0). The second value (ok) is a bool that is true if
>   the key exists in the map, and false if not.

This check is basically used when we are not confirmed about the data inside the map. So we just check for a particular key and if it exists we assign the value to variable. It is a O(1) check.

In your example try to search for a key inside the map which does not exists as:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    // We can store multiple items in a map as well

    superhero := map[string]map[string]string{
        "Superman": map[string]string{
            "realname": "Clark Kent",
            "city":     "Metropolis",
        },

        "Batman": map[string]string{
            "realname": "Bruce Wayne",
            "city":     "Gotham City",
        },
    }

    // We can output data where the key matches Superman

    if temp, hero := superhero["Superman"]; hero {
        fmt.Println(temp["realname"], temp["city"])
    }

    // try to search for a key which doesnot exist

    if value, ok := superhero["Hulk"]; ok {
        fmt.Println(value)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("key not found")
    }

}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/F_Ow0PoKXEP)

Comment: See also "Exploiting zero values": https://go.dev/blog/maps

Answer (score 2):

```
if temp, hero := superhero["Superman"]; hero
```

in go is similar to writing:

```
temp, hero := superhero["Superman"]
if hero {
    ....
}
```

Here is **"Superman"** is mapped to a value, hero will be `true`

else `false`

In go every query to a map will return an optional second argument which will tell if a certain key is present or not

https://play.golang.org/p/Hl7MajLJV3T

Answer (score 0):

It's more normal to use ok for the boolean variable name. This is equivalent to:

```
temp, ok := superhero["Superman"]
if ok {
    fmt.Println(temp["realname"], temp["city"])
}
```

The ok is true if there was a key in the map. So there are two forms of map access built into the language, and two forms of this statement. Personally I think this slightly more verbose form with one more line of code is much clearer, but you can use either.So the other form would be:

```
if temp, ok := superhero["Superman"]; ok {
    fmt.Println(temp["realname"], temp["city"])
}
```

As above. For more see [effective go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps) here:

> For obvious reasons this is called the “comma ok” idiom. In this
>   example, if the key is present, the value will be set appropriately and ok
>   will be true; if not, the value will be set to zero and ok will be
>   false.

The two forms for accessing maps are:

```
// value and ok set if key is present, else ok is false
value, ok := map[key]

// value set if key is present
value := map[key]
```

Comment: So, I can see in either case that `temp` must be assigned `superhero["Superman"]`.

And in your code, it is more clear what the other variable is doing. But what precisely does `ok` get assigned to...and why? How else might this sort of syntax show up in Golang?

Comment: Have a read of effective go (linked above) for more info. this is known as the comma, ok idiom. ok is assigned true if there is a value for this key in the map, or false if there is not  (in this case "Superman" is the key).