# Cannot assign value to an array in a structure in Golang

Tags: arrays, go, struct

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := make(map[string][3]float64)
    a["test"] = [3]float64{0.0}
    a["test"][0] = 1.0
    fmt.Printf("%v", a["test"])
}
```

Here is the playground [demo](https://play.golang.org/p/UKJj-ggsqG), which returns error

```
tmp/sandbox665292783/main.go:9: cannot assign to a["test"][1]
```

If I print the grammar of a["test"], it returns an array of len 3.

Comment: Assigning to an item in an array changes the value; it's like assigning to a struct field, discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751537/why-do-i-get-a-cannot-assign-error-when-setting-value-to-a-struct-as-a-value-i/32751792#32751792

Comment: To avoid the error, you either need to change the map value type (to []float64 or *[3]float64, for example) or construct a whole new `[3]float` to put back in the map (e.g. by explicitly copying the current value to a temp variable, modifying that, and assigning it back).

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the right direction!