# Why do keys and values from a map share the same memory address?

Tags: go

I notice that when iterating across keys and values in a map, they keys and values all share the same memory address. You can see that here:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    myMap := map[string]string{
        "hello": "world",
        "how":   "are",
        "you":   "today?",
    }
    for key, value := range myMap {
        fmt.Printf("Key: %p %v\n", &key, key)
        fmt.Printf("Value: %p %v\n", &value, value)
        fmt.Println("---")
    }
}
```

... which outputs ...

```
Key: 0xc00009e210 hello
Value: 0xc00009e220 world
---
Key: 0xc00009e210 how
Value: 0xc00009e220 are
---
Key: 0xc00009e210 you
Value: 0xc00009e220 today?
---
```

Why is that?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not taking the address of the values **in** the map. Actually, map elements are **not addressable** in Go. You are taking the addresses of the **local loop variables**, called "`key`" and "`value`". Those don't change across each loop iteration, because there is no reason for them to (they are re-used).

See:

[Why does Go forbid taking the address of (&) map member, yet allows (&) slice element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495402)